# Facebook PHP SDK misbehaving after December '12 updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the PHP (with js) SDK for authentication around my website.
Until now I've never had a problem with access tokens and everything has run smoothly. 
Since the latest updates have been pushed I'm receiving a lot of:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/content/54/9505854/html/src/fb/base_facebook.php on line 1106

The access tokens seem to be invalidated (or irretrievable) whenever there is a PHP call to the API. I made a simple page that uses and this has always simply returned the current access token as expected:

```
//Facebook PHP SDK
require_once 'src/fb/facebook.php'; 

//Config
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '...id...',
  'secret' => '...secret...',
));

$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
die($accessToken);
```

This page still works if loaded immediately after javascript authentication but any navigation away from this page (or indeed a refresh) this script will return the appID and secret as a string in the form `[appID]|[secret]`

Basically any call to the Facebook object makes the next page navigation unauthenticated.

Also I am not currently storing the retrieved access token as a cookie or in mySQL. Should I?

Any insight into the problem or solution would be really helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's a Facebook bug. Description can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/404450666302585

Answer (score 2):

This has now been fixed. Update to the latest version of the PHP-SDK (v3.2.2).

Answer (score 0):

I am using php-sdk "3.2.0" got same error..

As per new PHD-sdk mention above https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/commit/ca9472b3312dab3fdcfbffb4e45eb091f582dcb7

I have added following code-snippet which fetch saved access token from cache instead giving call to new access token using same code.

```
if ($code && $code == $this->getPersistentData('code')) {
          // short-circuit if the code we have is the same as the one presented
          return $this->getPersistentData('access_token');
}
```

Now, it is returning cache access token instead of [appID]|[secret] one.
It work for me.